# MongoDB disconnection invoke 2 db.on('close') events

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to connect to MongoDB server running on a docker container from my node server and retry to connect in an occation of a disconnection. I use the following code part to identify the disconnection and print out a log.

```
db.on('close', async ()=> {
                    self.databaseStatus = null;
                    self.mongoConnector = null;
                    LOG.error("MongoDB: Connection disconnected");
                    await self.initializeMongoConnector();
                });
```

But here is the console log when docker is stopped.

```
[2019-09-27T15:55:02.221] [ERROR] app - MongoDB: Connection disconnected
the options [servers] is not supported
the options [caseTranslate] is not supported
[2019-09-27T15:55:02.226] [ERROR] app - MongoDB: Connection disconnected
the options [servers] is not supported
the options [caseTranslate] is not supported
```

It prints the same error 2 times. And I think the db.on('close') event is fired twice. Can you give me a tip on why this is happening? I only need to catch one close event.